# apt-get is broken and can't install anything

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get, apt

My apt-get is totally broken and can't install anything. The output of 'apt-get install -f" is as follows:

```
# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-icon-theme : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but 3.4.3-1 is installed
 python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6) but 3.4.3-1 is installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but 3.4.3-1 is installed
 rhythmbox : Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.1-1ubuntu3) but 3.4.1-2ubuntu5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

The output of 'sudo apt install python3' is in the picture:[https://imgur.com/a/IbGK0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSF0F.png)

I have Googled any possible questions and tried any possible solutions but NO ONE worked for it.

Comment: Have you tried the steps described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't help. Any command about "apt" with "install" is broken. And the output is as follows:

Comment: # sudo apt-get clean
# sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-icon-theme : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (>= 3.6~) but 3.4.3-1 is installed

.........  (the same as the output got from 'apt-get install -f')

Comment: What do you get when you do 'sudo apt-install python3'?

Comment: # sudo apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-icon-theme : Depends: gtk-update-icon-cache

Comment: hplip : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python3 : Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.6.3-0ubuntu2) but 3.4.3-1 is to be installed
           PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.6.3-0ubuntu2) but 3.4.3-1 is to be installed
 python3-apt : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python3-crypto : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 python3-cups : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed

Comment: ......  rhythmbox : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
             Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.1-1ubuntu3) but 3.4.1-2ubuntu5 is to be installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.6.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Go to /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log and identify the packages that are broken. "apt-get remove" the packages, do release upgrade and then you should be able to reinstall them.

Comment: Note that for questions about software and OS usage/installation, we have _Super User_. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  _Ask Ubuntu_ would be OK here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log and identify the packages that are broken. "apt-get remove" the packages, do release upgrade and then you should be able to reinstall them.

You can find more information here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel

Comment: I had a package with dependencies issue, I've removed by `sudo apt-get remove <packageName> ` then I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade , after that things were ok

Answer (score 1):

This command resolved my error

> sudo apt -f install

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was behind a proxy, so I needed to run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

And added the following lines:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<user>:<password>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<user>:<password>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<user>:<password>@<proxy_host>:<proxy_port>/";
```